# Как переопределить метод Except в List?

Tags: c#, list

Есть два списка

```
var lst1 = new List<string> { "cat", "dog"};
var lst2 = new List<string> { "catty", "dogs"};
var rez = lst1.Except(lst2);
```

На данный момент я с помощью метода `Except` получаю нужные мне данные. Теперь понадобилось сравнивать данные по толерантности. Например, слово `dog` и `dogy` на процентов 80 идентичны. Для этого я использую расстояние Левенштейна. Как переопределить метод Except для этого?

```
static class LevenshteinDistance
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the distance between two strings.
        /// </summary>
        public static int Compute(string s, string t)
        {
            int n = s.Length;
            int m = t.Length;
            int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

            // Step 1
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return m;
            }

            if (m == 0)
            {
                return n;
            }

            // Step 2
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
            {
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
            {
            }

            // Step 3
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                //Step 4
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    // Step 5
                    int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                    // Step 6
                    d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                        Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                        d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            // Step 7
            return d[n, m];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Начните с постановки задачи. Что должен, в вашем понимании, вернуть вызов `new [] { "foo1", "foo2" }.Except(new [] { "foo3" })`?

Answer (score 4):

Напишите новый метод. Поскольку класс `List<T>` — класс фреймворка, можно сделать лишь метод расширения (extension), или статический метод *другого* класса с двумя аргументами.

Существующий метод переопределить нельзя. Если бы это было можно, то все методы фреймворка, которые используют его, внезапно стали бы работать по другому — а это привело бы к печальным последствиям.

---

Пример:

```
List<string> ExceptByLev(List<string> minuend, List<string> subtrahend, double threshold) =>
    minuend.Where(m => subtrahend.All(s => LevenshteinDistance.Compute(m, s) > threshold))
           .ToList();
```

---

Обратите внимание, что ваше «равенство» нетранзитивно. Это значит, что результат может зависеть от того, как именно производятся вычисления. В частности, если у вас есть два «равных» элемента, третий элемент может быть «равен» одному и «не равен» другому.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55665/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd----except--list).

Answer (score 0):

Метод Except подразумевает, что два элемента могут быть либо равны, либо не равны. То есть результат сравнения двух элементов должен быть булевого типа. От него и зависит попадет элемент в конечный список или нет (один, они ведь все равно равны).

При сравнении данных по толерантности нужно придумать критерий, по которому вы будете решать попадет элемент в результат или нет. Например, если слова идентичны на 80% и более. Но тут нужно понимать, что при одном таком сравнении будет добавлен один элемент списка, а не оба.

У метода Except есть второе определение с двумя параметрами:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer);
```

Вторым параметром он принимает интерфейс, который как раз будет использоваться для сравнения объектов. В вашем случае для типа string нужно создать класс, отвечающий этому интерфейсу:

```
private class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
                    int n = x.Length;
        int m = y.Length;
        int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

        // Step 1
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return m;
        }

        if (m == 0)
        {
            return n;
        }

        // Step 2
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
        {
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
        {
        }

        // Step 3
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            //Step 4
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {
                // Step 5
                int cost = (y[j - 1] == x[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                // Step 6
                d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                    Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                    d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
            }
        }
        // Step 7
        return d[n, m]; // переделать на что-то вроде условия > 80% для возврата bool
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

И далее вызывать метод Except с передачей экземпляра этого класса в качестве параметра:

```
var rez = lst1.Except(lst2, new MyComparer());
```